# backport security patch for https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23593 and https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23592 to 2.7

Tags: tensorflow

Noticed the security patch for https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23593 and https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2022-23592 is only available in 2.8.0, and the last sentence in the CVE is little confusing:

```
The fix will be included in TensorFlow 2.8.0. This is the only affected version.
```

Does it mean CVE-2022-23593 is not impact 2.7? If 2.7 is also relevant, do we have plan to backport the fix to 2.7?

Thanks